parsing Json Type Array(String) in ClickHouse
would you be so kind to help me to parse i.e. make structured table from the following JSON value I receive from base. type is defined as Array(string)
[{"id": 1, "categ": "abc", "fig": null, "goods": [{"g_id": 05, "code": "xxx" }, {"g_id": 06, "code": "xx2" }]},
{"id": 2, "categ": "de", "fig": null, "goods": [{"g_id": 07, "code": "xxx" }, {"g_id": 08, "code": "xx2" }]}]
I want to receive table with columns id, categ, fig, g_id, code.
id, categ, fig will repeat for goods list.
I tried JSOnExtract, but haven't received good result.

https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/f1a50d7d-d77b-4622-800b-c35616906a4f
create table t Engine=Memory empty as select * from format('JSONEachRow', '[{"id": 1, "categ": "abc", "fig": null, "goods": [{"g_id": 05, "code": "xxx" }, {"g_id": 06, "code": "xx2" }]},
 {"id": 2, "categ": "de", "fig": null, "goods": [{"g_id": 07, "code": "xxx" }, {"g_id": 08, "code": "xx2" }]}]') settings schema_inference_make_columns_nullable = 0, describe_compact_output=1;

set input_format_json_read_arrays_as_strings=1;

insert into t format JSONEachRow [{"id": 1, "categ": "abc", "fig": null, "goods": [{"g_id": 05, "code": "xxx" }, {"g_id": 06, "code": "xx2" }]}, {"id": 2, "categ": "de", "fig": null, "goods": [{"g_id": 07, "code": "xxx" }, {"g_id": 08, "code": "xx2" }]}]
;

select * from t format Pretty;

   +----+-------+-----+-----------------------+
   | id | categ | fig | goods                 |
   +----+-------+-----+-----------------------+
1. |  1 | abc   |     | [('xxx',5),('xx2',6)] |
   +----+-------+-----+-----------------------+
2. |  2 | de    |     | [('xxx',7),('xx2',8)] |
   +----+-------+-----+-----------------------+

show create table t format TSVRaw;

CREATE TABLE default.t
(
    `id` Int64,
    `categ` String,
    `fig` String,
    `goods` Array(Tuple(code String, g_id Int64))
)
ENGINE = Memory


JSONExtract does not work because of leading zeros 05 https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/66594
https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/5c647cdb-6add-4fdb-8c00-0faba2647a15
